# branch divergence in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am looking to change this code to prevent so much branch divergence

```
if (v == u) {
    ++c;
    ++u_t;
    ++v_t;
}
else if (v < u){
    ++u_t;
}
else {
    ++v_t;
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
u_t++;
if(v == u){
    ++c;
    ++v_t;
}
else{
    --u_t;
    ++v_t
}
```

Although this code is giving me the wrong answer for the whole program. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Who says there will be any branch divergence in that code?

Comment: `u_t` should not increment when `v > u` and in the failing sample it does always.

Comment: Are those floating point values? In such cases logic with Nan values is not boolean.

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to

```
if (v == u) ++c;
if (v <= u) ++u_t;
if (v >= u) ++v_t;
```

Can you optimise this? Not sure you can without knowing anything about the rest of the code.

Comment: but does my solution not give the same results always? I don't see how it is not equivalent.

Comment: @ta99mm your solution has no separate `<` or `>` comparison, it is basically either `==` or `!=`

Comment: `u_t += (v<=u)`

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik nice

Comment: @KillzoneKid maybe use of `u_t += signbit(v-u)` can be better.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik But what about if they are equal?

Comment: @KillzoneKid hmmm. Aren't they float? We may need to add a halo/tolerance value then. If they are int, then we can just add 1 and test for "less" instead of "less and equal". Maybe all these are not important and compiler does what we think. Its been developed by wise people after all :)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Seems OP has fundamental misunderstanding of conditional logic, so my attempt was to simplify his code for clarity.